# I have a Laravel project and want to add login with OTP using firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-authentication

I am working on a Laravel project, and I want to implement OTP-based login using Firebase. I have successfully implemented the code to send OTP and verify the phone number. However, I'm unsure about how to determine whether the user is verified on the server side and store their data in the local database once they are verified.

Here's what I have so far:

Routes:

```
Route::get('phone-auth', [PhoneAuthController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('verify-auth', [PhoneAuthController::class, 'verify']);
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class PhoneAuthController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
        return view('welcome');
        }

        public function verify(Request $request){
            // I need help with the server-side code here
        }
}
```

Blade:

```
   <!-- HTML and JavaScript code for sending OTP and verifying -->
   <!-- Firebase configuration is also included -->
```

In the verify method of my PhoneAuthController, I would like to:

Verify that the OTP entered by the user is correct on the server side.
Once verified, store the user's data in the local database.
I'm using Firebase for OTP verification, and the user's phone number is used for authentication.

Could you please provide guidance on how to implement these server-side actions? Specifically, how can I verify the OTP and store the user's data in the local Laravel database once they are verified?

Comment: What's your own attempt so far?